# What's the easiest way to get text onto a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, newsreader, readitlater

I can send a bunch of documents as attachments and have Amazon convert these documents and send them to my Kindle.  I do it all the time for .doc and .pdf files.

But what if there's a long email or article I want to read on my Kindle?  I don't want to have to open up Word, copy the article text to the document, save it, open up gmail, attach the .doc to the email, send it to the correct address, wait....

Is there a way that I can automate this process?  Is there a 'Read It Later' style bookmarklet or something that I can just click to send to my Kindle?

Comment: Calibre works well, but the newest generation of kindles can read pdf and txt files. The second generation can read txt, but not pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found something that works extremely well. [klip.me](http://www.klip.me/) is a bookmarklet and Chrome extension that sends the text and pictures on what ever page you're on to your kindle.  It's simple and quick.

The Chrome extension is way better than the bookmarklet, though.  Good for people who use Chrome all the time, not so good for people who use Firefox all the time (like me!).  The bookmarklet works, but it's spotty at times.  I find myself using the 'view this page in Chrome' add-on for Firefox and sending the page from Chrome.

Comment: I use the "Push to Kindle" Add-On from fivefilters.org on Firefox and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't looked at Read It Later, but [Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com) can reformat and [forward articles](https://www.instapaper.com/extras) to your Kindle, or you can download an omnibus and transfer it manually or use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) to do so automatically overnight.  You'll find a bookmarklet for it on the same page, or there are plugins for various browsers.

Calibre also has a recipe for Read It Later, it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get **text**, even rich text, on your kindle is to use http://pastepad.fivefilters.org/. If you want, they also have an [extension](http://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/) to send web pages. But for just pasting in text to send (even from another website), use the pastepad link.